# Few objects moving straight one by one in Unity

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine

I'am trying to create some snake-like movement, but i cant implement algorithm to move one body part straight by another and so on.

I wanna to have some auto-moved snake which consists of separate blocks ( spheres ). This snake should move along some path. I generate path with bezier spline and have already implemented one future snake's part along it. Point for head is obtained from spline by next api:

```
class BezierSpline
{
  Vector3 GetPoint(float progress) // 0 to 1
}
```

And than I have SnakeMovement script

```
public class SnakeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
  public BezierSpline Path;
  public List<Transform> Parts;
  public float minDistance = 0.25f;
  public float speed = 1;

//.....
void Update()
{
  Vector3 position = Path.GetPoint(progress);
  Parts.First().localPosition = position;
  Parts.First().LookAt(position + Path.GetDirection(progress));

  for (int i = 1; i < Parts.Count; i++)
  {
    Transform curBody = Parts[i];
    Transform prevBody = Parts[i - 1];
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(prevBody.position, curBody.position);

    Vector3 newP = prevBody.position;
    newP.y = Parts[0].position.y;
    float t = Time.deltaTime * dist / minDistance * curspeed;

    curBody.position = Vector3.Slerp(curBody.position, newP, t);
    curBody.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(curBody.rotation, prevBody.rotation, t);
  }
  //....
}
```

For now, if I stopped head movement all parts dont preserve distance and keep moving to the head position. Another problem with above algorithm is that parts don't exectly follow the head path. They can "cut" corners while turning.
The main idea is to have user/ai control for only head(first body part) and each followed part should exectly repeat head path and preserve distance between its neighbours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a snake like motion you are likely to get lots of strange behaviours if you treat spheres as seperate objects. While i can imagine its possible to get it to work, I think this is not the best approach.

First solution that comes to mind is to create a List, onto which you would add to index 0, on every frame, the position of the head of the snake.
The list would grow, and all the other segments would wait their turn, so lag x frames, and on each update segment y would have position of list[x*y]

If Count() of the list is greater than number_of_segments*lag, you RemoveAt(Count()-1)

This can be optimized as changing the list is somewhat costly (a ring buffer would be better suited, but a Queue could also work. For starters i find Lists much easier to follow and you can always optimize later). This may behave a bit awkward if your framerate varies a lot but should be very stable in general (as in - no unpredictable motion, we only re-use the same values over and over)

Second method:
You mentioned using a bezier spline to generate a path. beziers are parametrized by a float t so you have something like

```
SplineAt(t).
```

if you take your bezier_path_length and distance_between_segments, than segment n should have position of

```
SplineAt(t-n*distance_between_segments/bezier_path_length)
```